# How to update version of an indirectly referenced node module?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a library coming up deep in the node module hierarchy which is causing security issues. I am not directly referencing that module in my package.json. One of the module which I reference is loading up another module and that module is loading this module. So it's the third layer in the dependency tree. I can find out the library dependence tree using `npm ls`.
I tried updating package.json, but that's not correct I think.

How can I update the version of this particular module without touching the top modules? Should I have to use shrinkwrap?

Answer (score 0):

One (horrible way) (to answer your question directly) you could carefully manage all of those dependencies on your own and build that structure outside of NPM.  I hate it. There is a ton of dependency management overhead and no guarantee any of the hand assembled components would work together - so testing overhead too.  but in "theory" it could work.  FWIW I don't think shrinkwrap helps with sub dependencies at all.

I recommend this course (I understand this isn't what you asked for - but it is the best approach IMO):

1. Fork/Branch the library and make the change there.
2. Then issue a pull request (Back to the main branch)
3. Until it is is merged back in, you cab reference it via the GIT url in your package.json

from: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

> git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
>
> git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm#semver:^5.0
>
> git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git
>
> git://github.com/npm/npm.git#v1.0.27